# mvc 4 - Jquery mobile - @section scripts not working after navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-map

I'm newbie to mvc 4 and jquery mobile and what i'm trying to do is display a map using jquery-ui-map library.

Here is what I've:

1) On the layout page I've the following code at the bottom before "end of body" tag

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery","~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerymobile")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

2) On the Index View I've the following Actionlink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Display Map","Map", "Home", null, 
        new { data_role = "button", data_theme = "b", data_mini = "true" })
```

When I click on the above action link, It will take the user location and 'll display the marker on a google map.

On the MAP view page I've the following code at the bottom

```
@section scripts{

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/apis?sensor=false">
     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/map/demo.js")"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/map/jquery.ui.map.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/map/jquery.ui.map.overlays.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/map/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js")
    $(function () {
            //code to display the map
        });
 }
```

Here is the issue I'm having.... When I click on the action link it will display the Map View but no map is displayed.

If I refresh the page (f5 or click on browser refresh icon), it will call the `$function()` and the map is displayed.

1. Am I doing something wrong with `@section` tag?
2. How do I force the page to reload it.. I've tried do `Ajax.Actionlink`,  or set `cacheduration` to zero in Controller Action method, still no go.

I've tried all the available questions and answers in this forum and still I didn't get it to work.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Vow!! It took most of my day in figuring out this.... I've upgraded the nuget packages, to get the latest Web.Optimization and other dll's but still its a no go until now.

Finally, I came acorss this article by [Scott Hanselman's Create a great mobile site](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreateAGreatMobileExperienceForYourWebsiteTodayPlease.aspx).

As I was going through the article, I came across this script and put it in my _Layout page. Now my site works as expected....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
     // jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
     // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page), especially when going    back, hence disabling it.
     $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
  });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the ajax functionality you can also move the @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) is inside you data-role="page" div